# Abort Model loading in extjs

Tags: extjs

How to stop the model from loading, if an error is occurred and caught in the catch block?

Currently I am receiving a "loading.." status in my extjs page.

*SampleModel.js*

```
try {
    // Error occurs here
} catch (err) {
    // How to stop model from loading?
}
```

Comment: did you try hiding the load mask?

Comment: How are you firing the request? can you post that part? Because if you  are making the request programatically then changing the order of when to send those request could be the answer.

Comment: Why can't you use exception event ???